# fixing CSS dropdown

Tags: html, css

i want to make my drop down sub-menu straight with my drop down..
i don't know how to fix this problem. please help. please tell me is there any missing or incorrect code
here is my HTML code :

```
    <div id='TB001'>
        <ul>
            <li class='active'><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>contact</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>drop down</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">submenu2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href='#'>search</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

and here is the CSS :

```css
#TB001>ul{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background:rgba(0, 102, 102, 1);
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    border-radius:10px;
    line-height:15px;
}

#TB001>ul>li>a{
    padding:10px;
    margin:5px;
    font-size:16;
    color:white;
    float:left;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid black;
}

#TB001>ul>li:first-child{
    margin-left:20px;
}

#TB001>ul>li.active>a{
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 5px 10px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 5px 10px #000000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 5px 10px #000000;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#TB001>ul>li>a:hover{
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#TB001>ul>li>ul{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}

#TB001>ul>li:hover>ul{
    display: block;
    list-style:none;
    background:rgba(0, 102, 102, 1);
}

#TB001>ul>li:hover>ul>li>a{
    padding:10px;
    margin:5px;
    font-size:16;
    color:white;
    float:left;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your css by using this

```
#TB001>ul>li>ul{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top :45%
}

#TB001>ul>li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `li` elements positioned relatively so that absolutely positioned submenu would count its left/top position from the parent `li`:

```css
#TB001>ul>li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
#TB001>ul>li>ul {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/j6rwewhj/